# Why is the sequence, git add --all, git commit, then git push skipping files?

Tags: git

I have some new files in a new commit. I used:

`git add . --all` (I also tried `git add --all`)

to add the files, then:

`git commit`

to commit them, then I used:

`git push origin master`

to push them and everything went fine without error. However, upon logging on to my git server and listing the files with:

`git ls-tree --full-tree -r HEAD`

, certain important files are missing.

Also doing:

`git pull origin master`

On another machine seems to run fine without error, but those same files are missing.

Comment: after "git add --all" do a "git status" and see what files have been added for commit.  If the files you want aren't added then they are probably in your .gitignore file.

Comment: Formatting note: Indent your commands with four spaces, rather than surrounding them with back ticks, if they're on their own line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One common reason why files would be skipped is that they are in your `.gitignore` file. Check to make sure you aren't ignoring these file types, or the folders they are in.

Comment: That was why indeed. The issue was I didn't realize there were a bunch of `.gitignore` files in the repository, not just in the root directory.